# How to get PC Hardware information using Java or CMD

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I am creating a Java Desktop Application that is to report the Performance & Statistics of the Windows Machine (XP, Vista and W7).

Using Java or the Command Line how do I get the following information:

- Manufacturer (Dell, HP...)
- Modal Number
- Processor Type
- Processor Size
- System Type
- Storage Space
- RAM Total
- RAM Free or Used

And a reference page for this would be great, in case I find more information I want to list.

Comment: I can see a lot of related questions in sidebar. Did you go through those?

Comment: @VineetReynolds I searched Google and Stack Overflow and looked through several. But there's a couple on the right that I haven't seen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most of this should be queryable with WMI (which is what `systeminfo` very likely uses under the hood anyway – it just tends to gather *all* there is instead of specific information).

I hacked together the following small batch file. Not quite sure what you mean with *Processor Size* – no software will go into the computer case and measure the die dimensions, but maybe this comes close. You can do a `set` at the end of the batch file to view all created environment variables. Maybe some of them help:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%l in ('wmic computersystem get Manufacturer^,Model^,SystemType^,TotalPhysicalMemory /format:list') do >nul 2>&1 set "System_%%l"
for /f "delims=" %%l in ('wmic cpu get * /format:list') do >nul 2>&1 set "CPU_%%l"
for /f "delims=" %%l in ('wmic os get FreePhysicalMemory^,TotalVisibleMemorySize /format:list') do >nul 2>&1 set "OS_%%l"
set /a OS_UsedPhysicalMemory=OS_TotalVisibleMemorySize-OS_FreePhysicalMemory

for /f "delims=" %%l in ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^,FreeSpace /format:list') do (
    >nul 2>&1 set "TEMP_%%l"
    if "!TEMP_DriveLetter:~1,1!"==":" if defined TEMP_FreeSpace set StorageSpace_!TEMP_DriveLetter:~0,2!=!TEMP_FreeSpace:~0,-1!&set TEMP_DriveLetter=&set TEMP_FreeSpace=
)

echo Manufacturer: %System_Manufacturer%
echo Model: %System_Model%
echo Processor Type: %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
echo Processor Size: %CPU_AddressWidth%
echo System Type: %System_SystemType%
echo Storage Space:
set StorageSpace_
echo RAM total: %OS_TotalVisibleMemorySize% KiB
echo RAM free: %OS_FreePhysicalMemory% KiB
echo RAM used: %OS_UsedPhysicalMemory% KiB
```

Side note: This is free from locale-specifics, so it should work everywhere (as opposed to things like `dir | find "free"` for example). Code can be found [in my SVN repository](http://svn.lando.us/joey/Public/SO/6426778/info.cmd).

Answer (score 6):

**Manufacturer**

```
systeminfo | find "System Manufacturer"
```

**Model Number**

```
systeminfo | find "System Model"
```

**Processor Type**

```
echo %PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER% %PROCESSOR_LEVEL%
```

**Processor Size**

```
systeminfo | find "Processor"
```

**System Type**

```
systeminfo | find "System type"
```

**Storage Space**

```
dir | find "free"
```

OR

```
fsutil volume diskfree C:
```

**RAM Total**

```
systeminfo | find "Total Physical Memory"
```

**RAM Free or Used**

```
systeminfo | find "Available Physical Memory"
```

Comment: Dorothy: You can cache the output of `systeminfo`, obviously, which should speed things up a bit.

Comment: Deepak: Many of those are locale-dependent or don't work at all, either due to capitalization issues or due to the fact that `find` only returns a single line, which, e.g. for the processor is not enough.

Comment: you should use /FO SCV and parse it In java (just execute as external process) and process the info.

Comment: This solution may not be good in all cases because of the internationalization, if the application has to run on one or more computers that are not in English.

Answer (score 0):

Would psinfo from sysinternals do what you want?  You can run it from your server to query each PC.    http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897550

Comment: I'd prefer not to use this. Wouldn't I be able to use the same methods that this program uses to get the information I want?

Comment: Yes - it apparently uses the Remote Registry API   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315586