# Getting Manufacturer and Modal # from XP Home with Java or the Command Line

Tags: java, command-line, windows-xp, registry

How can I get the Manufacturer and the Modal Number of an XP Home computer? I asked a similar question 3 months ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6426778/476218). The answers were very helpful, but Windows XP Home Premium Edition does not have `wmic` or `systeminfo`. I looked in the registry on a few machines and did not find any consistent patterns.

Do you have any ideas? I'd like to stick with Java and the Command Line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REG QUERY HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS -v SomeValueName` gives you some info about the system, depending on what you use for `SomeValueName`.

`SystemProductName` returns the model of my laptop.  `BaseBoardProduct` has the same value, but it's entirely possible that the two will differ on some machines.  One of those should give you a model number.

`SystemManufacturer` and `BaseBoardManufacturer` have the name of my laptop's manufacturer.  Again, the two might differ.

You might be able to get the info by querying `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OEMInformation`, namely the "Model" and "Manufacturer" values.  But that looks like info that'd be stored during an OEM install (like when you use Dell's install disc to reinstall Windows on your machine), and may not be present (or may be useless) on home-built systems.

Note, the stuff returned by `REG QUERY` is in a particular format that you may need to parse.  It's not complex, but `REG QUERY /?` doesn't seem to mention a way to get rid of the headers and the REG_SZ and such that get returned.

(Also note: This is probably obvious to you...but the instant you use `Runtime.exec` to execute programs to query the Windows registry, you tie yourself to Windows.)

Comment: I've moved on to more important issues but will be readdressing this some time soon. I'll checkout these reg locations then.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to execute the appropraite windows command that inspects the registry, capture the output and parse it for the information you need.

Comment: That was not my question. I know how to run a command using Java I just don't know what command to run.